# Aligning on plus sign (as well as decimal sign) in tabular environments using numprint

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment

Is it a bug in the numprint package .. or maybe a missing feature? I can't align on the plus/minus sign in tabular environments, padding numbers with spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{numprint}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\nplpadding[\ ]{4}
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{N{4}{2}}}
  \toprule
  -940    & +1000   \\
  +952.38 & -1000 \\ \midrule
  +12.38 &     0 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Any hint welcome.

Comment: I do not know the `numprint` package, but [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) offers you aligning at the decimal sign.

Comment: In fact, numprint works correctly with the alignment at the decimal sign. The problem is the plus/minus signs ...

Comment: First instinct: `\nplpadding[\hphantom{0}]{4}`, but it fails. (A space has not the same width as a digit.)

Comment: I came to the same conclusion about the space width. Now, how to tell \nplpadding to use a blank character the same width as the surrounding digits?

Comment: I can only offer a manual solution (separate columns for `+` and `$-$`): `{*{2}{r@{}N{4}{2}}}`

Comment: Especially when you're dealing with numbers with decimal components, any alignment method *other* than on the decimal symbol (whether a `.` or a `,`) is likely to distract and even confuse your readers.

Comment: In this particular case, I want *also* to emphasize on the plus/minus signs themselves. If I don't pad, the sign of the result would be hard to see as the numbers could have very different magnitude.

Comment: You can (of course) do exactly what you want with a plain TeX halign... it's not pretty though :-)`\halign{&\quad\hfil$#$\hfil\ &\hfil$#$&$#$\hfil\cr
\toprule
-&940&    &+&1000&\cr
+&952&.38 &-&1000&\cr\midrule
+& 12&.38 & &   0&\quad\cr
\bottomrule}`

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I'd really prefer a more high-level solution :)

Comment: Yes, something high level would be nice, but I suspect you are swimming against the current on this one.  There's a short discussion in the TeX book on pp.240--241 which probably accounts for why it's hard.  Knuth implies that there are generally better typographical solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the [“good ol’ plainTeX” way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77639/aligning-on-plus-sign-as-well-as-decimal-sign-in-tabular-environments-using-nu#comment165263_77639), but you can use an additional column that is right aligned (as `+` and `–` have the same horizontal width the alignment doesn't really matter).

#### Basis

```
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{r@{}N{4}{2}}}
  \toprule
  $-$ & 940    &  +  & 1000 \\
   +  & 952.38 & $-$ & 1000 \\ \midrule
   +  &  12.38 &     &    0 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

The padding is still be done by `numprint` but with `@{}` we force that `+` and `–` are being typeset without any further space.

As this is probably needed a lot more times, with the use of the [`array`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package we define another column specification:

```
\newcolumntype{M}[2]{r@{}N{#1}{#2}}
```

It can be used, for example, as `M{4}{2}`.

Typing all those ampersands is a bit tedious so we make `+` and `-` active so that they insert the ampersands on its own, but we don't want this to affect the whole document, only our special `tabular` should have this effect, therefore I defined a new `ntabular` environment that is basically just a wrapper for a `tabular` environment with active `+` and `-`.

(I didn't introduce another character that “automatically” expands to `&`, because … you can just use `&`, can't you? Unfortunatly, this is still needed if you have no sign in front of a number.)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,numprint,array}
\begingroup
    \catcode`-=\active
    \catcode`+=\active
    \gdef-{$\char`-$&}
    \gdef+{\char`+&}
\endgroup
\newenvironment{ntabular}[1]{%
    \catcode`-=\active
    \catcode`+=\active
    \tabular{#1}
}{%
    \endtabular
}
\newcolumntype{M}[2]{r@{}N{#1}{#2}}
\begin{document}
Is it safe to use + and -?
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{ntabular}{M{3}{2}M{4}{2}}
  \toprule
   - 940    &  + 1000 \\
   + 952.38 &  - 1000 \\ \midrule
   +  12.38 &  &    0 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{ntabular}
\end{table}

Is it safe to use + and -?
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Why is there more space after the signs in the left hand column than the right hand column?

Comment: @Thruston Because the first `N` column uses 4 digits before the decimal point, too. Better use would be `{M{3}{2} M{4}{0}}`, I guess, but I didn't want to change the OP's column specification.

Comment: I like your solution. For the coumn specs, I wanted it simple. But indeed, I shouldn't be so lazy and adjust each column appropriately ;)